# Join two pipelinedRDDs

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, bigdata, rdd

I am trying to join two pipelinedRDDs using .join() in pyspart jupyter notebook

First RDD:

```
primaryType.take(5)

['DECEPTIVE PRACTICE',
 'CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT',
 'BURGLARY',
 'THEFT',
 'CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT']
```

Second RDD:

```
districts.take(5)
['004', '022', '008', '003', '001']
```

Join RDDs:

```
rdd_joined = primaryType.join(districts)
rdd_joined.take(5)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

What am I donig wrong here?

Comment: Don't you need pairRDDs to perform joins ?

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/api/pyspark/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html

Comment: OK I guess I'm missing something then .. so what's the expected output then ? Seems like you're joining crimes with potatoes :)

Comment: Btw : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.join

Comment: I guess I need to attach unique keys for every element in the RDDs, then join them?

Comment: Exactly ! To perform joins you need to have key-value pairs in your RDDs, and the join will retrieve values from both RDDs for a same key value.

Comment: still not working after each rdd has unique keys :-(

Answer (score 0):

There should be some unique key to join both the rdds, so use rdd.zipWithIndex() to create indexes for both the rdds and then try to join them

```
districts.take(5)
['004', '022', '008', '003', '001']

primaryType.take(5)

['DECEPTIVE PRACTICE',
 'CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT',
 'BURGLARY',
 'THEFT',
 'CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT']

districts=districts.zipWithIndex()

districts.take(5)
[('004', 0), ('022', 1), ('008', 2), ('003', 3), ('001', 4)]

districts=districts.map(lambda (x,y):(y,x))

primaryType=primaryType.zipWithIndex()
primaryType=primaryType.map(lambda (x,y):(y,x))
primaryType.join(districts).map(lambda (x,y):y).take(5)

[('DECEPTIVE PRACTICE', '004'), ('CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT', '001'), ('CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT', '022'), ('BURGLARY', '008'), ('THEFT', '003')]
```